# Runtime server in Spring tools suite 3.9.4 OSX

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite, pivotal-tc

I' m starting with Spring MVC. 
I work in a MacBook Pro with Spring Tools Suite 3.9.4.
I configure a Pivotal Server but when I try to add the libraries in my Java Build Path, STS don't find my Runtime Server. Add I can add Libraries.
In Windows I don't have this problem. 
Do you know if this is an issue in STS 3.9.4 Osx version?
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like a bug with Pivotal tc Server 4.0. If you download Pivotal tc Server 3.2.x and create a new runtime with tc Server 3.2.8 it would show up in the list of libs to add.
Can you please open an issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-tcserver ?
Thanks very much :-)

Comment: thanks, tomorrow I will try you solution and I tell you. Thanks

Comment: Added an issue here: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/157171003